# Rewrite Cond - bad flag delimiter .htaccess (Apache)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, delimiter

I'm trying to use the .htaccess to redirect bot / unwanted clients to an errorpage.
But on any connection it brings just "RewriteCond: Bad flag delimiters"

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} askpeter_bot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Jakarta [NC,OR]
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Genieo [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/bots\/notallowed.html" [F]
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Edit:
For now i'm using deny to block the user agents

```
deny from env=block
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "USER-AGENT" block=yes
```

But it's not the way i want to do because you just get an empty page and no message why

Comment: Try this `RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/bots/notallowed.html [R=403,L]`

Comment: Tried that. Same errormessage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the [F] or [R=403] flag, apache renders the [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument) for the specified code. You could set this using the ErrorDocument directive like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /bots/notallowed.html
```

The problem with this approach in your case is that it would be used for bots and humans alike when a 403 code is sent.

In order to limit this to bots, I suggest something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} askpeter_bot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Jakarta [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Genieo [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bots/notallowed.php [L]
```

Then in notallowed.php you could use the header function to send the correct header:

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"); ?>
Go away, bot.
```

If you're not using PHP, you could use perl, python, ruby, whatever. The key is sending the header from the script instead of relying on apache to send it in this case.

Edit:

Since you've already tried this, I think you may have a hidden control character of some sort on one or more of your rules. You can use cat to find these:

```
cat -v .htaccess
```

If that doesn't work for some reason, try this python:

```
python -c "f = open('.htaccess', 'r'); f.seek(0); file = f.readlines(); print file"
```

Comment: Already tried that, it's the same problem -> "Bad flag delimiters"

Comment: Odd, I tested that before posting and it was working fine. Do you have other rules in your .htaccess? What happens if you comment out everything but this rule? What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: There are alot more bot user agents in it (all in the same format like the ones in my question) but nothing else. I'm using apache/2.2.16 (Debian).
(And yes, mod_rewrite is loaded)

Comment: Nevermind... I was dumb... I just searched the .htaccess again and saw an unescaped space char...
Now it's working